# Deploying Firebase Storage Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

I have a project on firebase. Recently I have added firebase storage. But when I try to publish rules its throws the error :

```
=== Deploying to 'chatapp-86y5'...

i  deploying storage


There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Read access to project 'chatapp-86y5' was denied: please check billing account associated and retry

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

Commands I am using to deploy :

```
firebase deploy --only storage
```

I am able to deply my firestore security rules and can aslo deploy rules for storage through the Console.

Also when I go the link  https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine it prompts to setup a billing account for this project

Comment: The name of your project is "projectId"?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I removed it previoulsy

Comment: The error message is giving you two things to try.  Did you try them?

Comment: Is setting up billing account on  https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine for a project mandatory cause I havnt added one . I am confused because. I am able to update the rules on console of storage but cant do that with CLI. for storage alone

Comment: The error message is telling you to "check billing account".  If you think this is in error, you should take the advice of the error message an contact [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support). The volunteers on Stack Overflow can't help you with billing related issues..

Comment: Thank you Doug. I got a reply from Firebase support that suggested that I should upgrade to firebase tools latest version as "There was a change in realese which switched the checking of default bucket  from App Engine API to Firebase API". Now  I am able to push rules from terminal as well.